# Does NestJS has built-in tools for CRUD generation

Tags: node.js, nestjs

Does NestJS has built-in tools for CRUD generation like Loopback or Sails.js has? I really like the idea of NestJS but i don't want to repeat the same things in each Controller. I will be appreciative if someone could explain how can i reach it?

Comment: It has `nesjs-cli`. I tried to generate contoller, but error occurs `Error: Schematic "1" not found in collection "@nestjs/schematics".` https://github.com/nestjs/nest-cli

Comment: I'm getting data out of a Postgres db with the setup recommended in the docs.  However, I'm just finishing up studying the TypeORM docs and starting to code more functionality.  Going through the TypeORM docs is very important.  I played with Sails a couple of years ago but don't recall much.  With TypeORM you need to create an "entity" model for each table.  Each controller seems to live on its own with each entity but I'm not yet sure how much can be combined / DRY.

Comment: @Preston tools like TypeORM for Mysql/Postgres and Mongoose for Mongo incapsulate work with data structure, but you still need in each Controller methods say that you want use some ORM model and call methods of this model like find by id or create. Actually in general it is copy-paste... For now i see the only way is to create some BaseController which includes all routine works with Models. But i'm wondering does NestJS has some build-in tools for it.

Comment: @YaroslavDraga  Every controller is a route, something like /api/users.  Within that controller you have to put all the CRUD functions that are needed.  So you have to repeat all this for /api/products, /api/orders...  In Angular we can use variables in our functions so our http.service.ts file can serve many components.  It is DRY.  So far I don't see a way to do this in Nestjs.  However, the upcoming version 5 is supposed to be more like Angular.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, NestJS doesn't have this feature out of the box but you can use [nestjsx/crud](https://github.com/nestjsx/crud), It allows you to use all CRUD operation only by declaring an entity class. Check [the getting-started page.](https://github.com/nestjsx/crud/wiki/Controllers#getting-started)

EDIT: now NestJS has a built in schematics, you can find a [guide here](https://trilon.io/blog/introducing-cli-generators-crud-api-in-1-minute) on the trilon blog

Comment: Thanks, it was still actual for me after two years)